# How to integrate MongoKitten in an existing Xcode project (mac osx)using Swift Package Manager?

Tags: macos, xcode8, swift-package-manager, mongokitten

In my already existing mac app I use cocoapods to integrate certain libraries but I need to Integrate Mongokitten to this project using SPM.I don't understand how can I link my project to Mongokitten. Can anyone please help me find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

My general solution to people needing MongoKitten in a macOS/iOS project is to create a new SPM project and depending upon MongoKitten. You can then (using SPM) generate an Xcode project. `swift package generate-xcodeproj`.

The resulting `.Xcodeproj`. file will have access and will be linked to MongoKitten. You can then create an `.xcworkspace` for your project (if you don't have one already) and place both your existing Xcodeproject(s) in there as well as the newly created one by SPM. From here on, you can link the MongoKitten framework to your existing codebase from Xcode itself.